# Is is possible to not allow the user access to the Create CRUD after they've used it once?

Tags: laravel, crud

In an app that allows users to register their shop, I'd need them to be able to register only one and then no more. They'd still be able to modify the data, but they shouldn't have access to the "Create Shop" button/CRUD. Is it possible, and what would the best way to do it be?
(Using Laravel 7, VSCode, and MySQL)

Comment: if(auth()->user()->hasShop()){ throw new AccessDeniedException()}

Comment: there are many ways to do it.    create a method on your user model  canCreateShop() and return true or false based on if the user already has a record of that relationship.  return !$this->relation()->exists();   in your view check if(auth()->user()->canCreateShop())  show the button.

I personally would write a policy for your shop model,  on create check to see if the user already has one and return false,  then you can use the can()  helpers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's very possible! you could create a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware) add it to the route or the the fucntion that checks if the user has already a shop and if it is block him from adding new one

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (auth()->user()->shop) { //checks if the user has a shop or not 
        return redirect('home')->with(['message'=>'you can not create another shop']);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```